# Detect UpdateStdCost() ended

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to call the INUpdateStdCostProcess.UpdateStdCost() method in code but, I'm having a hard time detecting when the process has completed.  Apparently, it is asynchronous.  How can I do this?

```
INUpdateStdCostProcess costProcess = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INUpdateStdCostProcess>();
INUpdateStdCost standardCostGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INUpdateStdCost>();
foreach (INUpdateStdCostRecord costRec in standardCostGraph.INItemList.Select())
{
     costProcess.UpdateStdCost(costRec); // how to tell when done?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for a long operation using the UID of the graph running the process.

In your example you might have the following:

```
PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(costProcess.UID);
```